# Matrix with one label

Tags: math-mode, equations

good morning,

how I can do this equation in latex, please.

[image]

Comment: Short answer (because of the missing [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows what you've already done and can be used to try my suggestion and show you an answers): use one of the `case` environments of package `amsmath` resp. `mathtools`.

Comment: More precisely, I'd use the `dcases` or `dcases*` environment from `mathtools `. If you want to control thedistance between the matrices and the following text, use the `empheq` environment (from the homonymous package), combined with `alignedat`.

Comment: The question is unclear: you seems to be able to generate your equation. You do you have troube with latex ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let elaborate (for exercise) one of suggestion in above comments:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
f_e =   \begin{dcases*}
    \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} &  for $OS$, $ST$, $TW$, and $TY$   \\
    \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} &  for $OS'$, $SU$, $UW$, and $UZ$  \\
    \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} &  for $WX$, $XY$, $TW$, and $XZ$   \\
        \end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```